# Bokeh Plot access radio button active in callback of slider

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a scenario where I am using a slider and a radio button giving option let us say "A" and "B"

When the slider is changed I need to know the value of active radio button in the CustomJS function of slider.

Is this possible. I know I can access the value using cb_obj , but when callback is done via slider cb_obj would be slider and not my radio button group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the radio button as an argument to callback function.
For e.g.

```
radio_group = RadioGroup(
       labels=["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"], active=1,callback=callback_radio)
callback_slider.args["selected"] = radio_group
```